# Number of ways to paint a strip of $n$ slots using $k$ colors?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have $k$ colors, all of which must be used at least once. How many distinct ways are there to paint a strip of $n$ slots with these $k$ colors?

Stars and bars and multinomial coefficients don't seem to help.

Comment: By "strip" I take it the $n$ slots are in one row?  Does the same sequence from left-to-right count separately from right-to-left?

Comment: Yes, slots in a row, and order counts.

Comment: This counts some colorings more than once I think.

Comment: I believe @pjhuxford is correct. Consider 2 slots and 1 color, for example. The above gives $2$ choose $1$ different colorings. But there is only 1 way to color 2 slots with 1 color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** We use Inclusion/Exclusion. TThere are $k^n$ ways to do it, if we do not have the restriction that every colour must be used. Now remove the bad colourings, in which $1$ or more colours are missing.

There are $(k-1)^n$ colourings in which colour $i$ is missing. Adding up over all colours, that gives a preliminary total of $(k-1)^n$ bad colourings.

However, we have double-counted the colourings in whch $2$ (or more) are missing. There are $(k-2)^n$ colourings in which colours $i$ and $j$ are missing, for a total over all pairs of $\binom{k}{2}(k-2)^n$.

So our next estimate of the number of bad colourings is $k(k-1)^n-\binom{k}{2}(k-2)^n$.

However, we have subtracted too much. To count the bad colourings, we must add back the $\binom{k}{3}(k-3)^n$ colourings in which there are $3$ or more missing colours.

Continue.

For another view of the problem, please look at the Wikipedia article on Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.